# How can I see the NEST.SearchRequest.Type property's effect on my ElasticSearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm attempting to query a dynamic list of types in my ElasticSearch index using a NEST SearchRequest object.

```
public object Search(object runTimeData)
{
  var request = new SearchRequest()
    {
      From = 0,
      Size = 10
    };

  request = SetRouting(request, runTimeData);
  request = SetIndices(request, runTimeData);
  request = SetTypes(request, runTimeData);
  request = SetQuery(request, runTimeData);
  ...
  var results = _searchClient.Search<BaseOfAllTypes>(request);
  return results;
}
...
private SearchRequest SetTypes(SearchRequest request, object runTimeData)
{
  request.Types = GetTypesForRuntime(runTimeData);
}
```

If I call `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_searchClient.Serializer.Serialize(request))` through my debugger on the line where I perform the search, I don't see anything relevant to types in the JSON:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "my query data here",
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query results come back as though the types are being properly filtered, however.  Running that generated JSON directly through elasticsearch-head returns results for all types, so it seems as though there's something that I'm not seeing in the serialization of the request that I really ought to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "types" are present in the HTTP request header. What you're seeing is the HTTP request body. To get the request header, use

```
var requestHeader = results.ConnectionStatus.RequestUrl;
```

You'll also get the cluster address and index name information along with type information.

Beware, this works only when the `Search()` operation succeeds. Otherwise `results` can potentially be `null` and this statement will throw an NPE.